# Convert Arabic text to binary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arabic

I tried to convert some Arabic text to binary but may I have a problem.

```
def toBinary (self, message):

binary= ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in message)
print (binary)
```

when I enter English text it convert it correctly, I mean each 8 bits in group 
but if I enter Arabic text I think there is a problem because it grouped them with 11 bits each.

English example:

```
Enter your text: hello world
1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100
```

Arabic example:

```
Enter your text: السلام عليكم
11000100111 11001000100 11000110011 11001000100 11000100111 11001000101 100000 11000111001 11001000100 11001001010 11001000011 11001000101
```

I am using Python 3.6
and I am a beginner

any suggestions?

Comment: It takes 11 bits to represent the [Arabic codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)). What exactly were you expecting?

Comment: so that is normal ? i thought that it represented in 8 bits as English

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/